# iPhone and Android application to track friends on a map?

Tags: android, iphone-app

on iPhone there is a find my friends application, to show them on a map. Is there a similar application available that works on both Android and iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

**[Glympse](https://www.glympse.com/)** should be what you're looking for. It is available for [Android](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glympse.android.glympse), for [iOS](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=330316698&mt=8), and even for [Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/glympse/ec418e52-b788-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8). And it cares for your privacy: you decide who can see you, and for how long. That other person then gets a kind of "Token" which expires after the set time.

[image: Glympse on Android] [image: Glympse on Android] [image: Glympse on Android]
<sup>*Glympse* on Android (source: [Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glympse.android.glympse); click images for larger variants)</sup>

You can not only see where your friends are, you can also let the app guide you to them (or the other way around).

*Glympse* is available for free, well rated, and pretty famous amongst those who are familiar with the field.

Comment: Glympse is great for returning home or leaving a "breadcrumb trail" of your late night jogging. I go jogging at night, turn on Glympse and send the token to my wife's tablet. It shows where I am, and when I am expected to get back. If anything happens in the way, she knows that immediately-ish. Tons of other uses too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Waze](http://waze.com) for this.

It is primarily a navigation app which runs on iPhone, Android and Windows Phone but you can use it to see where your friends are.  You can also see your friends through the Waze website.

It is free to use.  You can follow multiple friends simultaneously.

I know there are some people who dislke Waze's privacy policy, so you may like to read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called ['Moby'](http://mo.by/) that lets a user share their location with others. It's available on iOS and on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobysys.moby&hl=en).