# End-to-end encrypted GPS-based friend locator for Android?

Tags: android, gps

There are a number of [iPhone and Android application to track friends on a map](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14675/iphone-and-android-application-to-track-friends-on-a-map).

However, as far as I can see, all of them work by sending your information to a central server. I realize that Google and my phone company already have access to this data, but I'd rather not increase that exposure, particularly to some random company of uncertain pedigree. Are there any applications (ideally open source) which use a serverless model, or which at least use client-side, end-to-end encryption?

Comment: Whatsapp uses end to end encryption on messages and location sharing both another app is telegram messenger. It's more secure than whatsapp but less pupular. Hope this solves your query!